# PHP - Date spans formatting

Tags: php, date, timespan

Is there a function or class out there that cleanly formats timespans with php?

Given 2 date-stamps:
it would check if the both dates have the same year. If so remove one.
Same month? remove one.

```
Example:
23 March 2002 – 13 January 2009  –>  23 March 2002 – 13 January 2009
23 March 2002 – 13 April 2002  –>  23 March – 13 April 2002
03 March 2002 – 15 March 2002  –>  03 – 15 March 2002
```

Maybe I should just do this with some if-else statements? It just looks messy but It might be the only way...

Just asking for some advice.
Thanks!

Comment: This does not sound like an issue that would be common enough to be served by the language or common code classes, but should be straightforward enough to implement in your own code base.

Comment: Read this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php. Using getdate function you could put your date information into associative array and then compare Day,Hour,Year,Month and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the built-in `Date` classes. They're really good. In this specific case, I think you're looking for [`DateTime::diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), which creates a [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object.